# Discord.js is não está esperando o retorno da função

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções

Estou desenvolvendo um BOT onde preciso fazer um request (GET) para uma API que me retorna um JSON. Essa parte aparentemente está funcionando corretamente, coloquei essa request em um arquivo separado e criei uma função pra chamar na minha função principal.

O problema é que quando chamo a função, antes de receber o retorno dela o meu programa já retorna `undefined` e alguns segundos depois a função termina de processar o request.

Como faço pra obrigar a a minha Main a aguardar o retorno da função?

Até tentei usar `async` e `await` mas sou bem leigo no JavaScript e não sei se está correto.

File apiCall.js

```
const config = require('./config.json');


function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
module.exports = {
        
    async apiGet(symbol){
        try{
            var http = require('https');
            var date = new Date();
            
            if(date.getDay == 6 ){
                date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);// se for Sabado pegar os dados de Sexta
            } else if(date.getDay == 0){
                date.setDate(date.getDate()-2);// se for Domingo pegar os dados de Sexta
            }else if(date.getHours > '18'){
                console.log('Horario OK');// pegando os dados de hoje pois a bolsa já fechou
                
            } else {
                date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);//Pegando os dados de ontem pois a bolsa ainda não fechou
            }
            
            var time = new Date();
            var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol='+symbol+'&apikey='+config.key;
            
            
            http.get(url, function (res) {
                var body = '';

                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    body += chunk;
                });

                res.on('end', function () {
                    var api = JSON.parse(body);
                    var apiString = JSON.stringify(body);
                    var fechamento = api['Time Series (Daily)']['2020-10-06']['4. close'];
                    console.log("API fechamento: ", fechamento);
                    var now = new Date();

                    var tempo = now.getMilliseconds() - time.getMilliseconds();
                    console.log(`tempo para a API fazer o request: ${tempo}`);
                    return fechamento;
                });

            }).on('error', function (e) {
                console.log("Got an error: ", e);
            });
        
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
    }
}
};
```

File LMF.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const api = require('./apiCall.js');



bot.login(config.token);

bot.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
   
    const CompleteMessage = message.content.toUpperCase();
    if(CompleteMessage.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

    let args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    switch (args[1]) {

             
        case 'teste':
                
                
                api.apiGet(args[2])
                .then(fechamento =>{
                     message.channel.send(fechamento);
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err);
                });                

                
                
                
                
                
                
            break; 

        default:
            message.channel.send("Para acessar a lista de comandos digite !LMF help");
            break;
        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema alterando o http request para um metodo sincrono usando o pacote sync-request no lugar do pacote padrão do JavaScript que eu estava usando.